# Redux and React. Does not change a content

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react and redux.
When I do a sort, the content doesn't re-render

Code:

```
case SORT_BY:

        //if (action.payload.group_id !== undefined)
        groups = state.groups;
        groups.map(
                (group, groupId) => groupId === action.payload.group_id
                    ? new Group (
                        group.title, group.tasks.sort(
                            function (a , b)
                            {return a.title > b.title;}
                        )
                    )
                    : group
        );
        return {groups};
```

I know the problem is somewhere here because redux compares the old object and the new. When they are compared, they are same. So, what should I do to get changing immediately? (content will change when I will do another func.)

[Here I have clicked to sortButton on the TaskGroup#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfBfN.png) - content doesn't changed

[Here I have added new task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWfCd.png) - and content changed and also, I get sorted task's list

App code (React Class where should content rerender)

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Group from './Group'
import AddGroup from './AddGroup'
import SortBy from '../components/Sort'

class App extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const groups = this.props.groups.map((group, index) => (<Group key={index} index={index} {...group} />));
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Tasks</h1>
                <SortBy/>
                <ul>
                    <AddGroup/>
                    {groups}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// groups from redux store is mapped to this.props.groups
export default connect(
    (state) => ({
        groups: state.groups
    })
)(App);
```

Group js

```
    import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import Task from './Task'
import AddTask from './AddTask'
import Sort from './Sort'
import {deleteGroup, reName} from "../actions/group";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

export class Group extends PureComponent {
    onDeleteClick = () => {
        const { deleteGroup, title } = this.props;
        // dispatch action
        deleteGroup(title);
    };

    onRenameClick = () => {
        const { reName, title } = this.props;
        // dispatch action
        reName(title, "group");
    };

    render() {
        // this.props.index contains group id (index in groups array)
        const tasks = this.props.tasks.map((task, index) => (
            <Task key={index} index={index} group={this.props.index} {...task} />));

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.props.title} <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick={this.onDeleteClick}/><input type="button" value="Rename" onClick={this.onRenameClick}/></h2>
                <ul>
                    <AddTask group={this.props.index} />
                    <Sort whatToSort={this.props.index}/>
                    {tasks}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, {deleteGroup, reName})(Group);
```

All reducer`s code

```
import Task from '../models/Task';
import Group from '../models/Group';
import {ADD_TASK, DELETE_TASK, TOGGLE_TASK} from '../actions/task';
import {ADD_GROUP, DELETE_GROUP, RENAME_GROUP} from "../actions/group";
import {SORT_BY} from "../actions/functions";

let g1 = new Group('Základní část',);
let g2 = new Group('Bonusová část',);

g1.addTask(new Task('přeškrtnutí splněného úkolu',true));
g1.addTask(new Task('přidání nové skupiny',true));
g1.addTask(new Task('odstranění skupiny',true));
g1.addTask(new Task('přidání a vypisování atributu počtu bodů ke každému úkolu'));
g1.addTask(new Task('přepočítání bodů při změně stavu (splnění) úkolu'));

g2.addTask(new Task('editace úkolu (názvu)',true));
g2.addTask(new Task('editace skupiny (názvu)',true));
g2.addTask(new Task('řazení úkolů'));
g2.addTask(new Task('řazení skupin'));

const initialState = {
    groups: [g1, g2]
};


export default function mainReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    let groups;

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TASK:
            // add new task to given group and left other groups intact
            groups = state.groups.map(
                (group, groupId) => (groupId === action.payload.groupId
                        ? new Group(group.title, [...group.tasks, new Task(action.payload.title)])
                        : group
                )
            );
            return {groups};

        case DELETE_TASK:
            groups = state.groups.map(
                // removes task (filter group tasks) from given group and left other groups intact
                (group, groupId) => (groupId === action.payload.groupId
                        ? new Group(group.title, group.tasks.filter(
                            (task, taskId) => (taskId !== action.payload.taskId))
                        )
                        : group
                )
            );
            return {groups};

        case TOGGLE_TASK: {
            // update task in given group and left other groups intact
            groups = state.groups.map(
                (group, groupId) => (groupId === action.payload.groupId
                        ? new Group(group.title, group.tasks.map(
                            // update given task and left other tasks intact
                            (task, taskId) => (taskId === action.payload.taskId
                                    ? {...task, done: !task.done}
                                    : task
                            ))
                        )
                        : group
                )
            );
            return {groups};
        }
        case ADD_GROUP:

            let doesExist = false;

            groups = state.groups.map(
                (group) =>
                {
                    if (group.title === action.payload.title)
                        doesExist = true;
                    return group;
                }
            );

            doesExist
                ? alert("This tasks group is already exist. Try to choose other name")
                : groups.push(new Group(action.payload.title));
            return {groups};

        case DELETE_GROUP:
            groups = [];
            state.groups.map(
                (group) =>
                {
                    if (group.title !== action.payload.title)
                        groups.push(group);

                    return group;
                }
            );
            return {groups};

        case RENAME_GROUP:
            let newTitle = prompt("Please enter new name of the " + action.payload.type);
                groups =  state.groups.map(
                    (group) =>
                    {
                     switch (action.payload.type)
                     {
                         case "group":
                             if (group.title === action.payload.title)
                                 group.title = newTitle;
                             return group;
                         case "task":
                             return new Group(
                                 group.title, group.tasks.map(
                                     (task) =>
                                     {
                                         if (task.title === action.payload.title)
                                             task.title = newTitle;
                                         return task;
                                     }
                                 )
                             );
                         default:
                             return group;
                     }
                    }
                    );
            return {groups};

        case SORT_BY:

            //if (action.payload.group_id !== undefined)
            groups = [...state.groups];
            const newgroups = groups.map(
                    (group, groupId) => groupId === action.payload.group_id
                        ? new Group (
                            group.title, group.tasks.sort(
                                function (a , b)
                                {return a.title > b.title;}
                            )
                        )
                        : group
            );

            return { newgroups };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

[Archive with all my code](http://yuriy.lesyo.eu/files/Archiv.zip)

Comment: this is not minimally verifiable. Please provide the necessary source code for us to reproduce the same problem.

Comment: I added. Is it enough? I don't think that problem is somewhere in react classes

Comment: Thanks. It's not about where you think the problem is, it's about giving us enough information to verify it ourselves, because you could've easily missed something while checking it yourself. That's why community has come up with this beautiful rule https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , which helps avoid all those questions in comments.

Comment: You are right. I will pay more attention to give enough information in the next time

Comment: I see you applied changes from different comments, for example here `return {newgroups}`. But if you change the variable to `newgroups` then I guess you should point it to `groups` key like `return {groups: newgroups}`

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I tried. Does not changing. I published .zip archive with my code.

Answer (score 0):

The code clearly lacks some essential information to make it verifiable, but one thing is for sure, that you forgot to return the new array from `groups.map`, since map is not altering anything in place, it returns the new array with mapped values.

So try this, maybe it can fix the problem:

```
groups = groups.map( ...
return {groups}
```

Comment: I return thats as object. Firstly I changed groups (by `map` method) and then I returned object with group (`{group}`).

Comment: Yes, I also tried it. It works same (content doesnt change, but sorting works). In any way, If I click to sort's button, content will not rerender, but data will sort. If I call other function, I get rerendering and I will see that elements were sortered

Comment: @YuriyLesyo then there is not enough info in the example, please update your code with minimum verifiable information https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This modifies the original `state.groups` pointer, which is bad. Do something like `const newGroups = groups.map(...); return { groups: newGroups }` instead.

Comment: No, since `groups = state.groups` just points a new reference `groups` to the underlying `state.groups` array, later we when do `groups = groups.map`, we make the `groups` point to a new array returned from `map`. `state.groups` stays untouched with the old array on its level.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan Yes, you are correct but my point is that so do the `state.groups`, since the code is doing `groups = state.groups;` prior. Therefore the "old" state would be pointing to the new array as well, and thus fails when doing a diff.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan You're right, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

The map method returns a new array. It does not alter the original array like you are expecting it to here.

Also, just looking at your logic, I think you would benefit more from the `reduce` array method rather than `map`

Comment: Yes, I do not get rerender, because redux things that I have same objects. I have no ideas how to fix that. I tried to use `.reduce()' but I don't know how can it help me

Comment: If I write 'groups = groups.map(...)' , content will not change

Comment: are you hoisting `groups`? It should be `const groups` if you're not? What are you expecting to change? Are you expecting differences in nested values?